# How to change "Leave a Reply" title in wordpress twentyfifteen theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, comments

I need to change Leave a Reply into Leave an Answer in Wordpress twenty fifteen theme.

I tried using comments.php file, but it is not working for me.

Is anyone have done this before or any idea to do this.?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WordPress default theme uses `comment_form()` to display the form. You can pass it an array as a parameter to indicate some options.
One of these options is `title_reply`: indicate a string, and you change the title!

`comment_form(array(
    'title_reply' => 'Leave an answer'
));`

See the [WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form) to learn more about this function.

Comment: Once I click on Leave a comment, it is saying leave an answer. I need to change that Leave a reply to Leave an answer too. That is working fine, means once I click on leave a comment, then comment title changing to the Leave an Answer.

Comment: All the strings can be modified. The corresponding options are documented on the WordPress codex page I linked above.